# How can I track distance traveled and Velocity of the robot?

Tags: ros, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the distance traveled and the avg velocity for a fitness evaluation for my robot. I can't find that information anywhere, though. Does anybody know of a package that publishes this information? I was hoping it was going to be part of move_base

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40176/how-can-i-track-distance-traveled-and-velocity-of-the-robot?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-07-30**:
What kinda robot are we talking about here?

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-30**:
The Turtlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That information is both in the transforms and odometry (http://ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-30**:
Yeah, that's what I thought. I was really hoping for something where I wouldn't have to keep track of position and twist, but if I must, I must. Linear twist is going to correspond to velocity, right?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-31**:
The current forward velocity is `twist.twist.linear.x`.To get distance you can integrate that over time, or sum the Euclidean distance from each previous position.